How to use library function correctly when editing OS- xv6 code using C?
I am adding some code into xv6 operating system,
I put #include "math.c" on the top of a new head file and code in this file and use log2 without any error warning, however, when I compile the whole project with make qemu, terminals threw out warning said: undefined reference to log2
How I suppose to solve this problem
this is how the exact problem
I tried to declare this library function in some other files, or reimplement it, but I don't know where to finish it.
I expect someone could taught me where to add this declaration or how to reimplement it.

Why are you trying include .c files into other .c files?

my bad, 'math.h' actually

Xv6 doesn't contain any C standard library, so you may have to implement the log2 function by your own. Besides, include a "*.c" file is not encouraged in the standard C programming. Furthermore, showing more about your file structure and some specific codes may help a lot!

I created a file named buddy.h in kernel part, adding the math.h standard function on the top of this file. Meanwhile I applied function log2 and exp2 in buddy.h, then I created a system call with some other operations by using buddy file.

I noticed that you use #include "math.h". Do you have math.h in the kernel directory? If not, and you want to use C standard library functions, you should change it to #include <math.h>.

Oops! It's my fault to misuse math.h. However, I tried  #include<math.h>  to use  standard library functions, but I still encountered such problem saying undefined reference to log2/exp2/malloc

I may have to try to implement the log & exp by my own. However, function malloc  has already been reimplement in directory user/umalloc.c , why malloc can't be recognized?

Because this malloc is not the same as the malloc that xv6 has implemented. The log function calls the malloc which the C standard library implements. Since the malloc function involves system memory allocation, xv6 must maintain the memory by itself; however, the C standard malloc manipulates your computer memory rather than xv6's memory! If you review the source code precisely, you may notice that xv6 does not use any standard library function. Therefore, I highly recommend you to implement the function only with the xv6 utility functions.

I 've tried to reimplement log2 & exp2 by myself, according to what u said, C standard malloc was no longer called in original log2,  however, when I used malloc again (it supposed to be malloc implemented in Xv6 itself) ,the problem still existed.

I checked malloc used in other file, here is an example in user/sh.c execmd(): struct execmd *cmd; cmd = malloc(sizeof(*cmd)),
below is what i wrote: struct *buddy self;  self = malloc(sizeof(2))

Could you show more about your code and compile command？It may help me figure out the problems. Or you can check whether you have included the  header file and compiled correctly.
